# Is it possible to send string into running process inside docker container?

Tags: linux, docker

For example i have running docker container with `cat` (or other process using stdin) defined in `CMD` Dockerfile option.

I'm trying to send string `test\n` into running `cat` (or other process).

Is it possible to do this, or I need to find workaround?

Sum up:
I'm looking for something like 
`echo 'test' | docker run -i --rm alpine command`
for *running* container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by simply pipeing stdin to docker attach, for example:

`$ docker run -i busybox sh -c "while true; do cat /dev/stdin; sleep 1; done;"
test`

and in another term

`$ echo test | docker attach <containerId>`

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe to `stdin` of the container's process if you start the container with `-i`. For example;

```
echo "foobar" | docker run -i --rm alpine cat
```

Keep in mind, that this is done when *starting* the container. Your question mentioned `cat`, which is not a long running process, so the container will actually exit after `cat` completes.

Comment: I know about `-i` parameter, and i'm looking for something like this for running container. `cat` is only example that accepts input

Answer (score 1):

Yes as an example see

https://github.com/chilcano/docker-netcat

you need to open a port, extract from the previous link

```
$ docker run -d -t --name=netcat-jessie -p 8182:8182 -p 9192:9192/udp chilcano/netcat:jessie
```

and now, you have some examples of communication using those ports
send traces to open a TCP port

```
$ ping 8.8.4.4 | nc -v 192.168.99.100 8182
```

or send traces to an UDP port

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8 | nc -vu 192.168.99.100 9192
```

or send traces to an UDP port without netcat

```
$ ping 8.8.4.4 > /dev/udp/192.168.99.100/9192
```

and

```
$ tail -f /opt/wiremock/wiremock.log | nc -vu 192.168.99.100 9192
```

or send traces to a TCP port without `netcat`

```
$ tail -f /opt/wso2esb01a/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log > /dev/tcp/192.168.99.100/8182
```

or send traces to an UDP port without `netcat`

```
$ tail -f /opt/wso2am02a/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log > /dev/udp/192.168.99.100/9192
```

Comment: So it's not possible to do it like `-X` parameter in `screen`?
Ex. `$ screen -S <name> -X <command>`

Comment: see docker exec if you want a shell inside a container https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/ if you want X in a container, you have to install a few things, see for example http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/

Comment: Nah, I don't want shell inside a container. I want to send a string into running process defined in `CMD` Dockerfile attribute.